# Organizing ASP.NET MVC Solutions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, business-logic, project-organization

I have been working on a large ASP.NET MVC 3 application for a few months now. It wasn't until late in the project that I realized that my controllers were HUGE! Part of the problem with these controllers being huge was that I couldn't unit test them.

I've since split the responsibilities of the controllers into four tasks (in my mind):

- navigation
- converting IDs to data objects
- building view models for display
- general-purpose business logic

Since some business logic is shared across client- and server-side code, it doesn't make sense to mix it in with view model builder logic. So, I immediately see the need for at least two projects: view model builders and general-purpose business logic.

I realized that navigation should be the responsibility of the controller, so that logic stays in the MVC project.

I am a little torn about which project should be responsible for converting IDs to data objects. Originally, I had made this the responsibility of the business class/view model builder class. However, I think I would like these classes to work primary with fully-constructed objects. So, I am not sure where in the code this conversion should take place. It doesn't seem to matter where I do the conversion, the code becomes duplicated. I have been thinking about creating adapters in the respective projects that do these conversions and then call the actual business class/view model builder class.

- Has anyone worked in an ASP.NET MVC project that has grown beyond a single project?
- How is logic broken out to keep the size of controllers down and keep code testable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Has anyone worked in an ASP.NET MVC project that has grown beyond a single project?

Yes.

> - How is logic broken out to keep the size of controllers down and keep code testable?

By [putting controllers on a diet](http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/).

Comment: I liked the discussion on using ModelBinders to convert keys to objects. I think using AutoMapper starts to break down when the logic gets more complex. For this, I am thinking about creating view model builders. When the logic for POST handlers starts to get more complicated, the IHandler classes used in this demo start to become as nasty as the original controllers. Nasty business validation logic also involves updating the ModelState.

Comment: One good thing about this demo is that it confirms that my latest approaches are moving in the right direction. Most of my controller actions are down to a few lines. I am using lots of ActionFilters, Ninject and a business logic layer to cut down my action sizes. It seems I have observed the same reoccurring theme. Yay, I'm not alone!

Comment: Linked video no longer exists.